# Teradata for Mac Type Lag

Tags: macos, teradata

As I query in editor, I experience a lag while typing. Closing the app and reopening solves the issue for a limited time but the issue comes back again. I have read several forums suggesting to change the .ini file. I have and still no luck. Here is what I have in Teradata.ini right now:

```
-vmargs
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=3072m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

Don't have this issue in my windows machine or VM. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you experiencing the lag with Teradata Studio (Express)? I have found that Studio and Studio Express can exhibit some lag if you have multiple query editors open and/or a few hundred lines of SQL. Try disabling auto completion and/or syntax checker and see if that helps improve the performance of the user interface. Push come to shove, if your can agree to the license agreement, I have found that SQL Workbench/J is a viable alternative to SQL Assistant for a Java based query tool that works with Teradata.

Comment: Hi @RobPaller, thank you for your post. Where do I go to disable auto completion and syntax checker? I have already disabled "Enable syntax validation" and "Code Assist Auto activation". Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Those sound like the correct settings in the Preferences. The next thing to try, although I stopped short myself, is to disable the syntax highlighting.